# package ‘Zelig’ is not available for R version 3.6.3

Tags: r, statistics, match

I want to use the Zelig package to get the ATT (Average treatment effect on treated) and ATE (Average treatment effect) after performing PSM (propensity score matching) using Nearest-neighbor matching method. 
After going through all the related issues I found that Zelig has no compatibility with R version 3.6.3. 
I would like to ask if there is any possible way to run the above package on **macOS Catalina 10.15.4** and  **R: version 3.6.3**.

If not, Is there any other way to get the **ATT** and **ATE** after performing PSM matching using MatchIt/Match. I would really appreciate a way out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Zelig has been removed from CRAN. See

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Zelig/index.html

On the [archive page](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Zelig/), the last version appears to have been `5.1.6`. You can get it using

```
remotes::install_version("Zelig", "5.1.6")
```